# Read JSON as a variable from a file

Tags: python, json

Trying to read a multi-line variable (JSON) from a file in python, but getting an error.

### #config.py

```
A = {    
  "query" : {
    "match_all" : {  }
  }
}
```

### #client.py

```
from config import *

print A
```

I get **{'query':{'match_all':{}}}** <--- double quotes are replaced with single quotes. Is there a way to preserve the original?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to preserve the original?

Comment: Python does that, you don't need to try to convert back to double quotes because it's not interfering with the integrity of the data.

Comment: You're right, I figured out that it's Python that does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single quotes are there as a result of Python's representation of strings.  If you really want the double quotes, you can do a trivial `str.replace`:

```
>>> print str(A).replace("'",'"')
{"query": {"match_all": {}}}
```